# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Konum"} was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native

[Code Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzjd9.png)

[Code Photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsZLT.png)

I have a stack navigator and bottomnavigator.I defined the 'Konum'page in the stack navigator.
I get this  " The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Konum"} was not handled by any navigator."error when I want to redirect to 'Konum'in an onpress.
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Konum')}   >

Can you help?

```
<Stack.Navigator    >
    <Stack.Screen  options={{headerShown:false}}   name='Home' component={Home}/>
    <Stack.Screen    options={{headerShown:false}}    name='Settings' component={Settings}/>
    <Stack.Screen    options={{headerShown:false}}     name='Profile' component={Profile}/>
    <Stack.Screen    options={{headerShown:false}}     name='Konum' component={Konum}/>
</Stack.Navigator>







  



<Tab.Navigator 
screenOptions={{headerShown:false,tabBarActiveTintColor:'#121212'}}
 >  




    <Tab.Screen 
     
    name="Home" 
    component={Home}
    options={{
        tabBarIcon : ({size,color})=>(
            <Feather name="home" size={30} color={'black'}/>
        )
        
    }
}

    />
    <Tab.Screen 
    name="Settings" 
    component={Settings}
    options={{
        tabBarIcon : ({size,color})=>(
            <Entypo name="plus" size={30} color={'black'}/>
        )
    }}
    />
    
    <Tab.Screen 
    name="Profile" 
    component={Profile}
    options={{
        tabBarIcon : ({size,color})=>(
            <Ionicons name="today" size={30} color={'black'}/>
        )
    }}
    />
    

</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define parent stack navigator which have your stack navigation and tab navigation like this.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator 
screenOptions={{headerShown:false,tabBarActiveTintColor:'#121212'}}
 >  




    <Tab.Screen 
     
    name="Home" 
    component={Home}
    options={{
        tabBarIcon : ({size,color})=>(
            <Feather name="home" size={30} color={'black'}/>
        )
        
    }
}

    />
    <Tab.Screen 
    name="Settings" 
    component={Settings}
    options={{
        tabBarIcon : ({size,color})=>(
            <Entypo name="plus" size={30} color={'black'}/>
        )
    }}
    />
    
    <Tab.Screen 
    name="Profile" 
    component={Profile}
    options={{
        tabBarIcon : ({size,color})=>(
            <Ionicons name="today" size={30} color={'black'}/>
        )
    }}
    />
    

</Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
<Stack.Navigator    >
    <Stack.Screen  options={{headerShown:false}}   name='Home' component={Home}/>
    <Stack.Screen    options={{headerShown:false}}    name='Settings' component={Settings}/>
    <Stack.Screen    options={{headerShown:false}}     name='Profile' component={Profile}/>
    <Stack.Screen    options={{headerShown:false}}     name='Konum' component={Konum}/>
    <Stack.Screen    options={{headerShown:false}}     name='MyTabs' component={MyTabs}/>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: not working,can you check my questions i added photos from code

Comment: @sweoguzhan can you please import your tab into stack navigation?

Comment: ı did it but not workin if u see stack and nav navigations on same page and ı import tab navigation into stack navigation as name=‘routes’ component=‘routes’ not working

Comment: @sweoguzhan can you please share your NavigationContainer screen? or did you try this? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Comment: Line 23 from the code image shows that have not included the Stack in your Navigation Container. Please provide your repo or share the NavigationContainer code as well. And please also make sure the components name start from capital letter always.